# Using .replace to replace a any combination of <b><u> and <i> tags

Tags: javascript

I'm using the `.replace` JavaScript method to replace `<b>`, `<u>` and `<i>` tags in a string.

```
var $text = 'This is some <b><u><i>bold underlined italic text</i></u></b>';
$text.replace(new RegExp('<(/?)b><(/?)u><(/?)i>','gmi'), '<div>').replace(new RegExp('<(/?)i><(/?)u><(/?)b>','gmi'), '</div>');
```

However this is not ideal because it only works if the tags are in that order.  it wouldn't work if my string was,

```
var $text = 'This is some <i><b><u>bold underlined italic text</u></b></i>';
```

Is there a method I can use that will allow for any combination of these three tags?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You`ll need to remove all **b,u,i** tags?

```
$text.replace(/(<\/?(u|i|b)>)/gmi,"")
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not create three RegExp and then just `$text.replace(regex1,'foo').replace(regex2,'foo').replace(regex3,'foo')`
where your regex1...3 would contain only one tag

It is stupid approach though, but also the simplest one and easy to understand, other thing might be to use | quantificator in your regex between all those tags.. e.g
**EDIT** This would create three times the foo, which you don't want.

```
$regexp = new RegExp('(<(/?)b>)|(<(/?)u>)|(<(/?)i>)','gmi');
```

**EDIT** And this option would suit you the best and according to @Vbyec you could write this in even nicer and shorter way

```
$regexp = new RegExp('(<\/?(u|i|b)>)+','gmi')
```

Comment: The problem with the first method would be that I would get foo three times, once for each tag.  But I want to replace all three with just one div tag

Comment: Ah yes, you are right. So in that case only the second option or as I just see the answer by @Vbyec does  the same.